# regex js how to to exclude from a match two consecutive zeros?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression

```
^[2-9][0-9]{3}-W([0-5][0-3]|(?!00))
```

https://regex101.com/r/OOCxzT/1

I need to exclude from the match a string with two consecutive 00 for instance

`2022-W00`

I added `(?!00)` but does not seem to work properly.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: [`^[2-9][0-9]{3}-W(?!00)[0-5][0-3]`](https://regex101.com/r/OOCxzT/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the negative lookahead in the alternation `([0-5][0-3]|(?!00))` this part `(?!00)` will be true (giving you a partial match) if the first alternative does not match, and from the current position what is directly to the right is not `00`

The lookahead should be right before the second match of the digits.

```
^[2-9][0-9]{3}-W(?!00)([0-5][0-3])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1hjnY/1)

If you only want to match 2 digits, you can also append an anchor `$`

```
^[2-9][0-9]{3}-W(?!00)([0-5][0-3])$
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ? or more digit after 'W' ?

```
^[2-9][0-9]{3}-W([0-5][1-3]|[1-5][0-3])
```

Comment: please remove questions from answer